# Plain Property in EmberScript

Tags: ember.js

How can I define a plain javascript property in EmberScript?

I mean I have my Router class which extends from `Ember.Router` which should also define a property called `location` like this

```
Router = Ember.Router.extend(location: FoobarENV.locationType)
```

If I try to define that in EmberScript like this:

```
class Router extends Ember.Router
  location: FoobarENV.locationType
```

Obviously I don't get the same code because `location` is translated into a property for the *Ember Object Model*, so the generated code looks like this:

```
Router = Ember.Router.extend({ location: get$(FoobarENV, 'locationType') });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the Ember getter/setter will work on any javascript object, so despite that being a little inefficient (drop in the pond) it will still work.